# Showing content view on top of a collection view xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, popup, collectionview, contentview

I have a page with a collection view. I have a button that allows the user to generate a pdf from the collection view data and share the pdf. the generation process takes a few seconds because there is a lot of data so I thought I should show something like a progress bar or progress ring to keep the user waiting and do nothing during this process. I tried to show something like a pop up using content view. this is the code: of the content view:

```
<ContentView x:Name="popupLoadingView" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="10, 0" IsVisible="false" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="White">

                        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Color="Black" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" ></ActivityIndicator>
                        <Label x:Name="lblLoadingText" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Loading..."></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
```

and this is the code of my collection view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="isc_alphaApp.Inventory">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems >

        <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary"
                     Text="logout"
                     Priority="2"
                  
                    />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="#ffc40c" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        
            <StackLayout >

                <SearchBar HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="search" BackgroundColor="#ffc40c"/>
               
                <CollectionView x:Name="lstl"
                  SelectionChanged="lstl_SelectionChanged"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                       
                >
                    <CollectionView.Header>

                        <Grid Padding="2" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1" >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="35" />

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="Code"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="Description"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" 
                                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    TextColor="Black"/>
                            <Label
                                 TextColor="Black"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Text="Unit"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                              HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                
                        />
                            <Label
                       Grid.Column="3"
                       Text="Qty"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                       />
                            <Label
                                 TextColor="Black"
                       Grid.Column="4"
                       Text="U.Price"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                       />

                        </Grid>

                    </CollectionView.Header>

                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Padding="1" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />

                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />

                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding itemcode}"
                      VerticalOptions="Center"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />

                                <Label 
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding name}"
                      
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />

                                <Label
                                Grid.Column="2"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding itemsunitcode}"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                        />

                                <Label
                      TextColor="Black"
                                Grid.Column="3"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       Text="{Binding currentQuantity}"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       />

                                <Label
                                Grid.Column="4"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       Text="{Binding CostPrice}"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       />



                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#ffc40c">
                    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckcol">
                        <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgAdd" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                        <Label Text="del" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}" x:Name="col_add_remove"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckfilter">
                        <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgfilter" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                        <Label Text="Filter" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckshare">
                        <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgshare" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                        <Label Text="Share" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarLabelStyle}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>

             
            </StackLayout>
        
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

i tried adding the content view code at the beginning of the collection view code, but it doesn't appear in the place intended. i want it to appear like an alert on top of the collection view layout and in the middle of the screen. this is the code of the pdf generation:

```
 shareTap.Tapped +=  (sender, e) =>
            {
                 popupLoadingView.IsVisible = true;
            activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
                requestPermission();
};
 async public void requestPermission()
        {
            var newstatus= Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Unknown;
            var status = Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Unknown;
            
            status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<StoragePermission>();


           
            if (status != Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                newstatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<StoragePermission>();
                if (newstatus == Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                   
                    generatePdf();

                }

            }

            else
            {
                
                generatePdf();
            }
            
        }

        private void generatePdf()
        {
            try
            {
                PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

                //Add a new PDF page.
                PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

                //Get the font file as stream.
                Stream fontStream = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("isc_alphaApp.Assets.arial.ttf");

                //Create a new PdfTrueTypeFont instance.
                PdfTrueTypeFont font = new PdfTrueTypeFont(fontStream, 14);

                //Create a new bold stylePdfTrueTypeFont instance.
                PdfTrueTypeFont boldFont = new PdfTrueTypeFont(fontStream, 14, PdfFontStyle.Bold);

                page.Graphics.DrawString("Items", boldFont, PdfBrushes.Black, PointF.Empty);

                //Create PdfGrid.
                PdfGrid pdfGrid = new PdfGrid();
                List<items_display> list_pdf = new List<items_display>();
                for (int i = 0; i < list_total.Count; i++)
                {
                    list_pdf.Add(new items_display { Code = list_total[i].itemcode, Description = list_total[i].name, Unit = list_total[i].itemsunitcode, Qty = list_total[i].currentQuantity, Price = list_total[i].CostPrice });
                }
                //Add values to list
                List<items_display> data = list_pdf;


                //Add list to IEnumerable.
                IEnumerable<items_display> dataTable = data;
                PdfStringFormat format_eng = new PdfStringFormat();
                format_eng.TextDirection = PdfTextDirection.LeftToRight;
                format_eng.Alignment = PdfTextAlignment.Center;
                //Assign data source.
                pdfGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
                pdfGrid.Headers[0].Cells[0].StringFormat = format_eng;
                pdfGrid.Headers[0].Cells[1].StringFormat = format_eng;
                pdfGrid.Headers[0].Cells[2].StringFormat = format_eng;
                pdfGrid.Headers[0].Cells[3].StringFormat = format_eng;
                pdfGrid.Headers[0].Cells[4].StringFormat = format_eng;
                //Assign bold font to pdfGrid header.
                pdfGrid.Headers[0].Style.Font = boldFont;

                //Assign font to PdfGrid.
                pdfGrid.Style.Font = font;
                Regex regex = new Regex("[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]");
                //Create String format with RTL text direction and center text alignment.
                PdfStringFormat format = new PdfStringFormat();
                format.TextDirection = PdfTextDirection.RightToLeft;
                format.Alignment = PdfTextAlignment.Center;


                for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (regex.IsMatch(data[i].Code))
                    {
                        pdfGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].StringFormat = format;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pdfGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].StringFormat = format_eng;
                    }
                    if (regex.IsMatch(data[i].Description))
                    {
                        pdfGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].StringFormat = format;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pdfGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].StringFormat = format_eng;
                    }
                    if (regex.IsMatch(data[i].Unit))
                    {
                        pdfGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].StringFormat = format;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pdfGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].StringFormat = format_eng;
                    }
                    pdfGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].StringFormat = format_eng;
                    pdfGrid.Rows[i].Cells[4].StringFormat = format_eng;
                }

                //Assign string format to draw RTL text with center alsignment
                //pdfGrid.Rows[0].Cells[1].StringFormat = format;
                //pdfGrid.Rows[1].Cells[1].StringFormat = format;

                //Draw grid to the page of PDF document.
                pdfGrid.Draw(page, new Syncfusion.Drawing.PointF(0, 20));
                String file_Path;

                string path = DependencyService.Get<getpath>().path();
                file_Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "items.pdf");
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(file_Path, FileMode.Create);
                document.Save(stream);
                
                //Close the document
                document.Close(true);
                
                Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
                {
                    Title = "Share PDF",
                    File = new ShareFile(file_Path)
                });
            }
           catch(Exception exp)
            {
                DisplayAlert("No Space", "Not Enough Storage!", "Okay");
            }

        }
```

The place where I try to make the content view visible doesn't seem to be right too because it is not displayed until the pdf is already generated. I want it to appear once the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make some changes to make it work

1. You need to use an `AbsoluteLayour` or `Grid` on your `Inventory` page. Because they allow "Stacking" views one on top of the other. Also here you need to add your loading screen.

If your `popupLoadingView` is in another XAML, you need to add it to your page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local=" <Insert your namespace here"
             x:Class="isc_alphaApp.Inventory">
 <!-- Rest of your code-->
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <local:popupLoadingView IsTrue="False" x:name="popupLoadingView"/>
        <StackLayout>
        <!-- Your collectionView goes here-->
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

2. After doing all the pdf work, remember to turn the Visibility to false

   ```
   shareTap.Tapped +=  (sender, e) =>
            {
                 popupLoadingView.IsVisible = true;
                 //Do all the work that you need
                 popupLoadingView.IsVisible=false;
           }
   ```

Comment: thanks a lot sir, the content view appeared above the collection view when i used the code you provided. but i have one problem, it doesn't appear until the pdf is already generated. i want it to appear during the process of generation. i don't know why but i think it's because of the pdf generation code. should i ask about this in a separate question?

Comment: because even the collection view stops scrolling during the pdf generation process

Comment: Your pdf work should work on a separated thread, it should not lock the main thread. To do this you might have to separate the event handler. Or just add the `async` like `sharedTap.Tapped += async (sender,e) => .....` but if you do that, you will have to do some modifications to your permissions and generation methods when you need the main thread